# Как менять версию PHP по умолчанию на сервере с ISPmanager и Centos 7?

Tags: php, centos, centos7, ispmanager

Как менять версию PHP по умолчанию на сервере с ISPmanager и Centos 7?

Щас есть вот эти версий:
[image]

командой:
`alias php='/var/www/php-bin-isp-php72/www-root/php'`
поменял алиас для комманды php думал что поменяеться и версия по умолчанию

но нет, не получилось

Может кто-то помочь?

PS. `php -v`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы неплохо увидеть **php -v** из консоли.
Ну а если в общих чертах:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Или

```
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

yum install yum-utils
```

Тут тоже на выбор

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70   [Install PHP 7.0]

yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71   [Install PHP 7.1]

yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72   [Install PHP 7.2]

yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73   [Install PHP 7.3]

yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
```

Comment: php -v добавил скрин

Comment: установить можно и из панели, а нужно менять версию по умолчанию